# As an admin, how do I manipulate a player's damage output on a 7 Days to Die server?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I'm an admin for a *7 Days to Die* server and have an annoying player. Do you guys know how I can manipulate his damage output? I'm a software dev but don't know how to manipulate individual profiles.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot manipulate individual players stats. Is banning the player not an option?

Comment: it is but he's a buddy so I'd like to troll him lol

Comment: Nevermind! had to add myself as the admin to the server and was able to just use the command line - thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind! I had to add myself as the admin to the server and was able to just use the command line.